# I can not change the color of the block

Tags: css, background-color

```
Сan't change background-color for intro block.
```

In the properties for the intro class, I apply the background-color property: # 31344e but the property is not applicabled. How can i solve this problem?

```css
@media all {

}
body {font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
 color: #6c7279;
margin: 0;
 background-color: #000000;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after{box-sizing: border-box;}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {margin:0;}

p {margin: 0 0 10px 0;}


/* Container
================*/
.container {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1170px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}




/* Header */

.header{position:relative;
 top: 0;
 left:0;
z-index: 1000;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;}

.header_inner {display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #515369;
 padding: 35px 0px;
 align-items: center;
}

/* Navigation */

.nav{font-size: 13px;
font-weight: 700;
text-transform: uppercase;
display: flex;
}

.nav_link {color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 opacity: 0.75;

transition: opacity .2s linear;
margin-left: 50px;}

.nav_link:first-child {margin-left: 0;}

.nav_link:hover {opacity: 1;}

}

/* Intro
========================*/

.intro{height: 750px;
 width: 1900px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: #31344e;

}

.intro_tittle {font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 65px;
color: #ffffff;
font-weight: 700;
margin: 0;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: center;
line-height: 1.1;}

.intro__subtitle {font-size: 22px;
 color: #ffffff;
 line-height: 1.5;
font-weight: 400;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 30px;}

.intro_inner {max-width: 970px;
width: 100px;
margin: 0 auto;}

/* _______button */

.button {

wertical-align: top;
font-size: 13px;
color: #ffffff;
font-weight: 600;
text-transform: uppercase;
display:inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 14px 40px;
 border-radius: 2px;
 margin-top: 60px;

}

.button--red{background-color: #e84545;
 transition: background-color 2s;
}

.button--red:hover {background-color: #ec2323;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>ActiveBox</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cardo:ital@1&family=Open+Sans:wght@700&family=Raleway:wght@400;600;700&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<!---- Header ---->

<header class="header">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="header_inner">
   <div class="header_logo">
    <img src="img/activebox-logo.png" alt="">
   </div>
   <nav class="nav">
    <a class="nav_link" href="#">Features</a>
    <a class="nav_link" href="#">Works</a>
    <a class="nav_link" href="#">Our Team</a>
    <a class="nav_link" href="#">Testimonials</a>
    <a class="nav_link" href="#">Download</a>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </div>
</header>

<!--- Intro --->

<div class="intro">
 <div class="header_inner">
 <div class="container"><h1 class="intro_tittle">Your Favorite One Page Multi Purpose Template</h1>
 <h2 class="intro__subtitle">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusamus asperiores aspernatur atque aut
   autem corporis, delectus deleniti eius eveniet fugit hic magnam necessitatibus perferendis perspiciatis
   possimus quaerat tempora voluptatibus?

  <p><a href="#" class="button button--red">ind Out More</a></p></h2>
 </div>
</div>
</div>

/*______Features_____*/

<div class="container">
 <div class="features"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Сan't change background-color for intro block.
In the properties for the intro class, I apply the background-color property: # 31344e but the property is not applicabled. How can i solve this problem?